# Dataframe memory usage different between sys.getsizeof and pandas memory_usage

Tags: python, pandas, operating-system, sys

I am working with a dataframe that is taking up nearly all the memory I have available in my Jupyter notebook. The dataframe is called df. When I use the .memory_usage method it looks like my dataframe is only consuming 1.4GB:

```
df.memory_usage(index = True).sum()

1453433764
```

This # seems too low since I am approaching my memory limit of 16GB. When I use the sys library I get a different result:

```
import sys
sys.getsizeof(globals().get('df'))

6792997032
```

sys.getsizeof returns 6.8GB which seems more accurate.

I'm curious why there is a discrepancy between the two?

If helpful, this dataframe is created by reading a bunch of different csv files and using the pandas concat method to stitch them together while overwriting the df object each time I use df.concat.

Thanks very much for the help!

Comment: did you try passing `deep=True` to `memory_usage`?

Comment: "If helpful, this dataframe is created by reading a bunch of different csv files and using the pandas concat method to stitch them together while overwriting the df object each time I use df.concat." Not really relevant to the question at hand, I don't think, but this is an anti-pattern and can deteriorate into quadratic performance pretty quickly. Instead, *append to a list* of dataframes and do `pd.concat` on taht list at the end

Comment: To add to the `deep=True` comment: from the documentation: "The memory footprint of object dtype columns is ignored by default" (hence the need for `deep=True`).

Comment: Thank you for the comments! Yes, I was missing deep = True, the two match when I use this argument.